# Is {0} a free module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Is $\{0\}$ a free module (over any ring $R$) ?

A free module is isomorphic to $R^n$, but is $n=0$ allowed?

Alternatively, a free module is defined to have a set of linearly independent generating sets, in this case it would be $0$ but I recall by definition in the case of vector spaces that $0$, by itself, is dependent.

However $\{0\}$ is torsion free as the only torsion element is $0$. (I know torsion free does not imply free, but this fact seemed relevant to me).

The thing is, there is a result I need to use which has free modules among the hypothesis and I am too lazy now to check if the proof of that result is ok for $\{0\}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would say yes, it has the empty set as a basis.

Comment: most certainly!

Comment: @IttayWeiss How can the empty set be a basis? A basis is supposed to span the module, but I think the empty set doesn't span anything.

Comment: Since $0$ is an empty sum (the sum of $0$ things), the empty set spans $\{0\}$.