# Is $\{ 0 \}$ a basis of the free module $\{ 0 \}$?

Tags: modules

I'm studying modules by reading Dummit and Foote, and I'm having a problem understanding the definition of a free module. I read [this stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058022/is-0-a-free-module), but I couldn't figure it out.

The textbook defines a free module as following:

[image: definition of a free module]

The following is the example that I'm confused about.

Let $F = \{ 0 \}$.
Then $F$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module since $F$ is an abelian group under addition.

In [the stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1058022/is-0-a-free-module), the empty set is given as the basis for $F$.
That makes sense because $F$ has no nonzero elements, so it satisfies the definition vacuously.

But, using the same logic, wouldn't $F$ be a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module on the set $\{ 0 \}$?

I think that would be a problem because if that was the case, the rank of $\{ 0 \}$ would be both 0 and 1.

Comment: No, $\{0\}$ is not a free module on one generator.

Comment: Can you explain how I can get to that conclusion using the definition I posted?

Answer (score 4):

The set $\{0\}$ is not linearly independent, because $r0=0$ for any nonzero $r\neq 0$.

The empty set *does* span the zero module, because an empty sum is zero.

Comment: It looks like $\{0\}$ is a basis over the null ring, though.

Comment: I don't think the definition I posted (the one from Dummit and Foote) mentions anything about linearly independent sets.

Comment: That definition is equivalent to: (1) $A$ spans $F$, and (2) $A$ is linearly independent. Think about it: clearly $1\cdot 0 = 0 = 0\cdot 0$, so $0$ does not have a unique representation as a combination of elements of $\{0\}$.

Comment: I'm not sure if that answers my question. The definition I posted states "nonzero element x of F, there exist..."

Comment: Okay, it's just a weird definition. I think most algebraists would agree that a basis is a linearly independent spanning set. A free module with a finite basis should be isomorphic to $R^n$, but this fails if you're using D&F's definition. Rank should be the cardinality of a basis, and should uniquely determine a free module (over a commutative ring).

Comment: So, with D&F's definition, $\{ 0 \}$ is indeed a basis of the free module $\{ 0 \}$?

Comment: Sure. But be wary that now you can have non-isomorphic free modules of the same rank (namely $\{0\}$ and $R$ both have rank $1$).